# Magento 2.1 : Grid duplicate checkbox id_ issue on add new and edit form

Tags: magento2, grid, grid-serlization, checkbox

[image]

```
<input name="" value="3" id="id_3" class="checkbox admin__control-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
```

I Want to check/unchecked the tags and holidays to attach them to my store as shown in the picture, but the ids of the checkboxes conflict with each other;as they appear duplicate from both tags and holidays- if you check id 3 of holiday it will also check the id 3 of tags, in both grids the ids appear in the format **id="id_3"**.How can I change the format **id_x** to something like **idz_x** .

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_gmaps',
            [
                'header_css_class'  => 'a-center',
                'type'              => 'checkbox',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_gmaps',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'holiday_id',

            ]
        );
    $this->addColumn(
        'holiday_id',
        [
            'header' => __('ID'),
            'sortable' => true,
            'index' => 'holiday_id',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
        ]
    );
    $this->addColumn('holiday_name', [
        'header'    => __('Title'),
        'align'     =>'left',
        'index'     => 'title',
     ]);
     $this->addColumn('holiday_name', ['header' => __('Holiday Name'), 'index' => 'holiday_name']);
    $this->addColumn('holiday_description', ['header' => __('Holiday Description'), 'index' => 'holiday_description']);
    $this->addColumn(
        'position',
        [
            'header' => __('Position'),
            'type' => 'number',
            'index' => 'position',
            'editable' => 'false'
        ]
    );


    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

And the entire row is

```
<tr title="#" class="even _clickable">
<td class="col-in_gmaps">
    <label class="data-grid-checkbox-cell-inner" for="id_3">
    <input name="" value="3" id="id_3" 
    class="checkbox admin__control-   checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="id_3"></label></label>
    <td class="col-ol_id">3</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue , if someone encounters a similar situation - you can resolve the conflict by adding 'use_index' => true in your _prepareColumns() method. This allows you to choose your custom column ,which can be used as your index for ids.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_xyz',
            [
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_xyz',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'hu',
                'use_index' => true

            ]
        );
```